# sum to last row minus 1 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I have `column M` full of data and then at the bottom of the data, a header.

I need to sum all of `column M` minus that header, then put it in a column under that header.

I am new to macros and have been trying to figure it out to no prevail. here's what i have tried :

```
With Over65
Over65M = Over65.Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)


Over65.Range("M5:M1000").Find("").Formula = "=sum(M5:M" & Over65M & ")"
End With
```

Please help!

Comment: You could use the `SUM` function for the complete range including header if the header contains text because text will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that (sorry, I needed to use Sheet1 as an example; feel free to change it):

```
Sub SumValues()
    Dim Over65              As Worksheet
    Dim Over65M             As Long

    Set Over65 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With Over65
        Over65M = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("M5:M1000").Find("").Formula = "=sum(M5:M" & Over65M - 1 & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```